# Use local Python Program to Update AWS Database for use by AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Ok. So I need some direction.

I have a python program called Wally Flow running on my local machine. It updates data in text files. These text files are read by the python Flask Ask program I've written which feeds the data to a corresponding Alexa Skill through ngrok.

I want to move the Flask Ask program to AWS Lambda.

I need a way for the local python program (Wally Flow) to update the data in the cloud that is then accessed by the AWS Lambda which serves as the end point for the Alexa Skill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As copied from your other question here: [AWS Lambda w/Ask Flask Retrieving Data on Local Machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49602618/aws-lambda-w-ask-flask-retrieving-data-on-local-machine/49602788#49602788)

One way to achieve that would be outputting those text files to S3 instead of the local filesystem. Using boto3 you can then read those in your Flask-Ask skill. You can test this even without using AWS Lambda at first, because you can both read on write to S3 from your local machine, and then later migrate to AWS Lambda.

See the Boto3 guide for S3 here: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3.html

For running Flask-Ask on AWS Lambda you might want to take a look at https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa which makes that fairly easy.

Comment: I was wondering what happened to that question. I wrote it on my phone and it disappeared. It looks like logging in with facebook made a new account?

But thank. That is exactly what I needed. I just didn't know the name of the service S3 so I didn't know how to get started

Comment: Right, that makes sense :)